# SQL flag several rows based on criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table structure like this, with let's say two columns. One column is the id, the other column is some kind of a flag, where I write the id from other rows, to group them by a certain criteria.

In the initial step, I'm populating the `identicalFlag` column with the own `id`. So after initialization, the table looks like this:

| id | identicalFlag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |

I then find the predecessor of a row, based on a timestamp and several other criteria. Based on these criteria, we can build groups. We can assume, that the timestamp order is like the id's, so `1` is the predecessor of `2`, `2` of `3` and so on. `1` does not have a predecessor.
Based on the other criteria, we are grouping. We will only expect groups of size one, two or three. So for example we would group `1`, `2` and `3` as one group, `4` as a second group with only one element, and `5` and `6` as a group with two elements.
Note: Based on the other criteria, `1`, `4` and `5` will not find a predecessor.

The entries in the table are pieces, produced by machines. The timestamp is the entry point of the piece in the machine. The pieces are organized in campaigns. Since this table holds the data of all machines, we want to only have the "real" predecessor if the machine is equal. Therefore we have the additional criteria, not only the timestamps. I can't group by the machine, since I also have to take in account the timestamp and therefore the order.

I changed the logic from before, to now write the `id` (instead of the `identicalFlag`) of the predecessor of the current row in the `identicalFlag`, if it's a predecessor based on the criteria. That will generate a chain between `id` and `identicalFlag`.

The table after the update statement looks then like this:

| id | identicalFlag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 5 |

My code to achieve this looks like that, and building the chain is working perfectly fine:

```sql
UPDATE c1
SET c1.identicalFlag =
  CASE
    WHEN criteria_for_predecessor THEN c2.id
    ELSE c1.identicalFlag
  END
FROM c1
INNER JOIN c2 ON c2.Timestamp < c1.Timestamp
```

The `INNER JOIN` with `c2` will produce either 1 or 0 results. `c2` is the predecessor in the example.

I now need somehow a second update statement, to traverse the chain.
The anchor would be `id` = `identicalFlag` and all the rows from that traversion path (plus the root) need to get the same value for `identicalFlag`. Easiest would probably be, to set all the `identicalFlag` values to the root of the chain, I think. That should also cover the special cases with only one row per group (here `4`).

Thanks

Comment: Your question is quite hard to follow, it would help to strip it down to just the initial data and your desired results. Why is 4,5 not following the same pattern, I would expect 4,5,6(if present) to have 5 as the identical value. Please simplify and clarify.

Comment: I have edited my question. I left the intermediate tables, because that shows, how the data could be updated during the execution, showing the order. The logic is not the same pattern for every pair of rows. Actually, I would be happy to have either 1, 2 or 3 as the identicalFlag. It should just be the same value for all three in this case.

Comment: Could it be, that it's not working at all, because it's running in a transaction and therefore it will never see the new value `identicalFlag`? In this case, I would only get a maximum of 2-pairs, never more, since it's not finding the others...

Comment: You left out too much information... Can you do the whole update at once? Or use some sort of temp table where you update the information as you go, but you always have the original rows also

Comment: Yes, the update is running at once, updating approximately 100k rows. There is not the possibility to use a temp table.

Comment: Due to halloween protection, your update cannot do things "in order", actually it doesn't see the new values when it calculate another value. so whatever you think happens probably doesn't. you can think of the join as being a "copy" of data, so when you update values, they aren't seem by the "old" part of the join

Comment: Ok, thanks @siggemannen! I will check my alternatives on that.

Comment: You might want to think if you are approaching this problem correctly in the first place. Maybe your data can be modeled differently. Maybe you don't need to update columns in place but can apply the logic for grouping in your queries, view or stored procedures. It is hard to tell anything from this example because it seems very artificial and lacks context.

Comment: Agree with @topsail. But if i'm guessing right, you have some sort of duplicate match system, where users can be connected by multiple properties. These kind of problems usually require a side-table of some sort, and i'm not sure why you cant use it

Comment: It''s really unclear what end result you want. At the moment it sounds as if all rows should just have the same number. Please give more sample rows and explain the logic behind their results.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far! I updated the question and I could achieve a small goal, by 
generating a chain for grouping the data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, using this query:

```sql
WITH [root] AS (
SELECT [id], [identicalFlag] AS [identicalFlag] FROM c1 WHERE id = identicalFlag AND [id] IN (SELECT [identicalFlag] FROM c1 WHERE [id] <> [identicalFlag])
),
    chain AS (
    SELECT *, 0 AS [Level] FROM [root] WHERE [id] = [identicalFlag]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [c1].[id], [chain].[identicalFlag] AS [identicalFlag], [chain].[Level] + 1 FROM [c1]
    INNER JOIN [chain] ON [c1].[identicalFlag] = [chain].[id]
    WHERE [c1].[id] <> [c1].[identicalFlag]
)
UPDATE c1 SET [identicalFlag] = [chain].[identicalFlag]
FROM chain WHERE chain.id = c1.id AND [chain].[Level] > 0
```

Thanks for all the replies